# Возможно ли эту задачку решить на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет, у меня есть вопрос. Преподаватель сказал, что эту задачку невозможно решить на Пайтоне. Вот задача:

> Определите длину кратчайшего пути между пунктами B и C. Передвигаться можно только по дорогам, протяжённость которых указана в таблице.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли сделать эту задачу на Пайтоне? И если да, можете скинуть решение и объяснить мне как вы это сделали.

Comment: Ну наверное тут проще всего граф использовать и библиотеку `NetworkX`. Загнать данные в граф и спросить кратчайший путь. А если без библиотеки, то довольно муторно - придётся самому граф делать.

Comment: Извини, но можешь примерно показать, как сделать самому граф в ответе @CrazyElf

Comment: Мне тоже сразу же пришел в голову алгоритм Прима.

Comment: Это простая задача на нахождение [кратчайшего пути в неориентированном графе](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8).    `Преподаватель сказал, что эту задачку невозможно решить на пайтоне.`  - это препод так "на понт" берёт или ваша инициатива?

Comment: работа алгоритма Дейкстры полностью разжевана в книге "Грокаем алгоритмы", хотя сложного в нем ничего нет. Уж преподаватель точно должен его знать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делаю за вас задание только потому, что мне полезно было освежить знание [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/index.html), так то я сам почти с нуля это по его документации написал и по другим ответам на SO:

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from((('A','B',3),('A','C',7),('A','F',2)))
G.add_weighted_edges_from((('C','D',3),('C','E',1)))
G.add_weighted_edges_from((('D','E',1),('D','F',2)))
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G,pos)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels)
print(nx.dijkstra_path(g, 'B', 'C'))
print(nx.dijkstra_path_length(g, 'B', 'C'))
```

Вывод:

```
['B', 'A', 'F', 'D', 'E', 'C']
9
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну, судя по картинке, всё правильно. Короткий путь `B->A->C` весит 10, а найденный алгоритмом Дейкстры длинный путь весит 9.

А если вам надо вообще без библиотек, то это вы уже дальше сами. По идее алгоритм Дейкстры не сложный в реализации.

Comment: Спасибо, что объяснил мне